# HTML not being escaped correctly on "exact duplicate" form

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

I just saw this when [closing a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840504/how-can-i-style-input-file-textbox)...

[image: Escaping problem]

Looks like HTML is not being encoded correctly.

Comment: Heh, I just fired an E-Mail saying the same. :) Is this new, or is this just the first time it's come up and we happened to see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed and deployed - thanks for the report!